# How to mass remove files that contain special characters in file name

Tags: linux, grep, filesystems, command-line-interface, rm

Google Drive went a little crazy and create multiple iterations of files by appending multiples of  "(1)", "(1) (1)" to the file names. So far I've been able to get a decent list of them with their path by using:

`tree -f -ifpugDs $PWD | grep -e '(1) (1)' | cut -d "]" -f 2 > output.txt`

Now I'm having trouble on how to delete them with the rm command. I Don't mind deleting a few of them by hand that the filter didn't pick up ( like "(2) (1)" ), but there are around 45K of them that the filter matched with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete every file whose name ends in `(1)`, recursively:

```
find . -name '*(1)' -exec rm {} +
```

- `-name '*(1) (1)'` to only delete files ending with a double 1.
- `-name '*([0-9])'` will match any single digit.
- `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*(1)' -exec rm {} +` for no recursion.
- I would do `find . -name '*(1)' -exec echo rm {} \;` to print a neat list of the `rm` commands to be executed. Review it, then remove `echo` to run for real.
- Changing `\;` back to `+` is optional, `+` is more efficient.

Comment: you can also use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} +` (supported by GNU find, not sure about other implementations)

Comment: It's not portable, no. Although the question is tagged linux, so it's probably GNU find.